# Mongoose validation and GridsFS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like add a mongoose validation in my code but I don't have a ".save method" in my code. It's because I use GridFS who to manage the save in the Database.

My question is simple. How get I a mongoose error with a other method.

This is a example of code.
First part, the schema

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
color: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

mongoose.model('mySchema', mySchema);
```

Second Part, the JS Code
Normally, you have this code.

```
var mySchema = mongoose.model('mySchema');

function upload(req, res){

var name = req.body.name;
var color = req.body.color;

var myUpload = new MySchema({
    name: name,
    color: color
})
myUpload.save(function(err){
    if(err){
    console.log(err)
    }
  })
}
```

But me, I don't have this code because GridFS manage all. So, how catch a error while schema execution if i don't have this code, but gridFS ?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking here. I don't think you really understand what schema validation means here, and could therefore probably do with an example of what you "think you mean" by showing exactly what "errors" you expect to catch.

Comment: Fine. I would like to upload a file with two others values in my database.

I do my upload with Postman. 
file : /path on my file
name : sunshine
color : yellow

I have a schema for to can in my Database

var amazingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name : {
type: String,
required: true
},
color : {
type: String,
required: true
},
})

Comment: If I upload a file without the field color, my request is break, it's great but me, I want get the error in a console.log.

All documentation in mongoose use .save for get a error but with GridFS, i don't use .save. GridFS valide only the content of file.


I hope it's a little clearer...

Comment: Not really. You are being asked to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50131695/edit). If you see comments, then that is what we are really asking for and not more comments. Also when I say "show us" I mean to basically show a document in JSON form, and as an example of what you think "errors" and what does not. If you don't really understand something then rather than trying to explain in words it's much clearer to show the examples instead. So that was why you are asked to do that.

Comment: Ok sorry, I modify my text